# Set Timer on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, timer

Im trying to execute the function pepe() repeated times, i get no errors but it doesnt work.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyClass {
    var timer = Timer()
    @objc func pepe() -> String {
        let hola = "hola"
        return hola
    }
    func startTimer(){
         let seconds = 1.0
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: seconds, target: ().self, selector: #selector(pepe), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }
    func stopTimer() {

        timer.invalidate()

    }

    init() {
        self.startTimer()
        self.stopTimer()
    }
}
var pepe = MyClass()
pepe.stopTimer()
pepe.startTimer()
```

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest:

1. Don't instantiate an empty `Timer`. Consider:

   ```
   var timer = Timer()
   ```

   That is creating a blank timer instance. We don't want to do that. You should instead use:

   ```
   weak var timer: Timer?
   ```

   That achieves a few things:

   - The `Timer?` syntax says it's an "optional", whose value you will instantiate later.
   - When the `Timer` is scheduled, the runloop keeps a strong reference to it. So, unlike most other objects, you don't personally need to keep a strong reference to your scheduled timers. And you might want the `timer` variable to be automatically set to `nil` when the timer is invalidated. So, the `weak` qualifier says that when the timer is invalidated, the `timer` variable will automatically be set to `nil`.
2. The `pepe` method signature is not quite right:

   - It shouldn't return anything;
   - You should probably give it the `Timer` parameter. It's a good habit to get into. You might not need it here, but it makes the intent of the method more clear and you may eventually find it useful to have that `Timer` parameter; and
   - I might give it a more descriptive name to avoid any ambiguity; I tend to use names like `timerHandler`.
3. There's no point in starting and stopping your timer in `init`.
4. That reference to `().self` in the `target` should just be `self`.
5. In your playground, you're stopping the timer (that hasn't been scheduled started yet) and then starting it.

   You might also want to stop it after a little time, so you get a chance to see the `Timer` in action.
6. But, as general rule, when writing method to start the timer, it is prudent to make sure you hadn't (accidentally) already started it. If you don't do this, and accidentally call `startTimer` twice, you can end up with multiple timers going at the same time (and worst, having lost references to the earlier timers). One common solution typical solution is to see if there is a already timer, and if so, invalidate it before you create you next timer. This is easily accomplished with the optional chaining pattern:

   ```
   func startTimer() {
       timer?.invalidate()   // stops previous timer, if any

       // now proceed with scheduling of new timer
   }
   ```

Thus:

```
import UIKit

// if doing this in playground, include the following two lines

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

// MyClass

public class MyClass {
    weak var timer: Timer?

    @objc func timerHandler(_ timer: Timer) {
        let hola = "hola"
        print(">>>> \(hola)")
    }

    func startTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()   // stops previous timer, if any

        let seconds = 1.0
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: seconds, target: self, selector: #selector(timerHandler(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}

var object = MyClass()
object.startTimer()

// stop it 10 seconds later
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
    object.stopTimer()
}
```

It should be recognized, though, that you can end up with something akin to a strong reference cycle:

- The runloop keeps a strong reference to scheduled timers;
- The selector-based timer keeps strong reference to its `target`;
- The `MyClass` (the `target`) is what presumably is responsible for eventually invalidating that timer.

As a result, `MyClass` can't be deallocated until the `Timer` is invalidated. And, as it stands, you cannot just `invalidate` the `Timer` in the `deinit` of `MyClass`, because `deinit` won't get called until the the timer is invalidated.

The net effect is that if you have, for example, this `MyClass` as a property of your view controller and start the timer and then dismiss the view controller, the timer will keep going and `MyClass` won't be deallocated.

To solve this, you might want to use closure based timer with `[weak self]` reference, eliminating the strong reference between the timer and `MyClass`. You can then also automatically invalidate the timer when the `MyClass` is deallocated:

```
public class MyClass {
    weak var timer: Timer?

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    func timerHandler(_ timer: Timer) {
        let hola = "hola"
        print(">>>> \(hola)")
    }

    func startTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()   // stops previous timer, if any

        let seconds = 1.0
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: seconds, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
            self?.timerHandler(timer)
        }
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer bro. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Set `repeats = true`  , make it `self` not `().self` , I tried this and it works , also you have a mistake of trying to start and stop the timer in `init`

```
public class MyClass {
    var timer = Timer()
    @objc func pepe()  {
        let hola = "hola"
        print("\(hola)")
    }
    func startTimer(){
        let seconds = 1.0
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: seconds, target:self, selector: #selector(pepe), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    func stopTimer() {

        timer.invalidate()

    }

    init() {

    }
}
```

Comment: You run it on playgrounds? i get this error:
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PeopleViewController: UIViewController {

    var countdownTimer: Timer!
    var totalTime = 0

    let timerLbl: UILabel = {

        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22)
        lbl.text = "HH:MM:SS"
        return lbl
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        totalTime = defaults.integer(forKey: "time")
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(timerLbl)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            timerLbl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            timerLbl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            timerLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
            ])
     //   startTimer()

//        doBackgroundTask()

        UIApplication.shared.runInBackground({
            self.startTimer()
        }) {
            // task after expiration.
        }
//        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
//
//            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.startTimer), name:UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
//
//        })
    }



//    deinit {
//        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
//    }

//    var backgroundUpdateTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
//
//    func doBackgroundTask() {
//
//        DispatchQueue.main.async {
//
//            self.beginBackgroundUpdateTask()
//
//            self.StartupdateLocation()
//
//            self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()
//
//        }
//    }

//    func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() {
//        self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
//            self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()
//        })
//    }
//
//    func endBackgroundUpdateTask() {
//        if let bgTask = self.backgroundUpdateTask {
//            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
//            self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
//        }
//    }
//
//    func StartupdateLocation() {
//        startTimer()
//    }

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    @objc func startTimer() {
        print(countdownTimer)
        countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateTime() {

        print(timerLbl.text as Any)
        defaults.set(totalTime, forKey: "time")
        let updateTime = defaults.integer(forKey: "time")
        timerLbl.text = "\(timeFormatted(updateTime))"

        totalTime += 1

        defaults.set(totalTime, forKey: "time")
//        if totalTime != 0 {
//            totalTime += 1
//        } else {
//            endTimer()
//        }


    }

    func endTimer() {
        countdownTimer.invalidate()
    }

    func timeFormatted(_ totalSeconds: Int) -> String {
        let seconds: Int = totalSeconds % 60
        let minutes: Int = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60
        let hours: Int = totalSeconds / 3600
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours,minutes, seconds)
    }


}


extension UIApplication {
    /// Run a block in background after app resigns activity
    public func runInBackground(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void, expirationHandler: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let taskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier
            if let expirationHandler = expirationHandler {
                taskID = self.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: expirationHandler)
            } else {
                taskID = self.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: { })
            }
            closure()
            self.endBackgroundTask(taskID)
        }
    }

}
```